# Change in observable array in side observable array not updating UI in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation, knockout-3.0

```
var subject = function (data) {
  self = this;
  self.subjectName = ko.observable(data ? data.subjectName : "");
  self.subjectPassPercentage = ko.observable(data ? data.subjectPassPercentage : "");
}

var course=function(data){
  self = this;
  self.courseName = ko.observable(data ? data.courseName : "");
  self.subjectList = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

view modal

```
app.viewmodal = (function (ko) {
  "use strict";
  var me = {
    subjectObject: ko.observableArray([]),// Array of subject
    course: ko.observableArray([])// Array of course
  }
  return me;
  })(ko);
```

on click, I am executing below code

```
me.course()[0].subjectList().push(me.subjectObject()[0]);
```

and in HTML I am trying to print the count

```
<div data-bind="text:viewmodal.course()[0].subjectList().length"></div>
```

But the change in the array subjectList is not reflecting in UI. It is always showing 0.

But when I click below div then it gives the correct count in the console log.

```
<div  data-bind="click: function(){ console.log(viewmodal.course()[0].subjectList().length)}">Click Me</div>
```

Please help me in identifying the problem and suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that code:

```
me.course()[0].subjectList().push(me.subjectObject()[0]);
```

Calling `.subjectList().push(...)` unwraps array in observable and push object directly into it - by doing that you are bypassing all ko mechanisms.
[Documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) says:
***pop, push, shift, unshift, reverse, sort, splice**
All of these functions are equivalent to running the native JavaScript array functions on the underlying array, and then notifying listeners about the change*

So to fix this you just need to remove parenthesis when calling `push` on your observableArray like that:

```
me.course()[0].subjectList.push(me.subjectObject()[0]);
```

That will notify ko about your changes and UI should be updated